# Custom minimize button loses original minimize button animation

Tags: vb.net, animation, minimize

I would like to know if there is a way of keeping the Original Animation to keep my VB application as close to original as possible.

```
Private Sub Minimize_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Minimize.Click
        Me.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Minimized
End Sub
```

I expect the minimize action to play the animation that ocurs in most if not all of the windows applications.

[Edit]:
All the apps I have installed have the default minimize animation because they all use the same windows bar, but my program doesn't because I find it not very attractive, so I created my own [Print](http://prntscr.com/of9wmc) By programming the button myself I lose the animation.

Comment: The code posted does not interfere with the animation.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the opacity to create an animation of sorts.

```
Private Sub Minimize_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Minimize.Click
    For disapper As Single = 1.0! To 0 Step -0.2!
        Me.Opacity = disapper
        'Me.Refresh()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
    Next
    Me.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Minimized
    Me.Opacity = 1.0!
End Sub
```

Comment: That looks even better than the original animation in my opinion. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

So I found that the problem is that my formborderstyle propety is set to none and the animation isn't shown when it is set to none I solved it by doing this, but even tho it works it worses things even more... For now I will stick with having no animation at all unless someone finds a solution. Thanks.

```
Private Sub Minimize_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Minimize.Click    
    Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle
    Me.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Minimized
    Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Any app minimization animation is in windows settings, and can be turned off anyway. I Don't think you can force it if you have it disabled in your userprofile System Properties settings. 
This can be found in sysdm.cpl in Advanced -> Performance

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. All the apps I have installed have the default minimize animation because they all use the same windows bar, but my program doesn't because I find it not very attractive, so I created my own [link](http://prntscr.com/of9wmc) By programming the button myself I lose the animation,